# Explain the output of below java code

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Can anybody explain why output to below question is "A.test" ?

```
class A {

   private void test(){

      System.out.println("A.test");

   }

   public void mytest(){

      this.test();

   }

}

class B extends A{

   protected void test(){

      System.out.println("B.test");

   }

}

public class Test{

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      A a = new B();

      a.mytest();

   }

}
```

Comment: Hint: try using your favorite search engine the next time ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The `test()` method of class `A` cannot be overridden by class `B`, since it is `private`. Therefore `this.test();` invokes `A`'s `test()` method even though it is executed on an instance of class `B`.

Answer (score 0):

*Super class can invoke the methods of the sub class without using typecasting, without using reflection and without using a reference other than `this` only if they are **overridden**.*

In your case `A a = new B();` , object of `B` is created which has both the behaviours `private void test()` as inherited by super class `A` as well as `protected void test()` as added by `B`. The reason for both the methods being there and not just one is that due to the acess modifier being `private` the method is not visible in subclass scope. Hence it can not overriden and adding the method with same name just simply adds another method.

As **there is no run time polymorphism** in this case hence compile time target method is resolved and method defined in `A` is invoked.

If in case you would have overriden the `mytest` in `B` and from the overriden `mytest` you would have made a call to `test` then method in `B` would have been invoked. This is easy to understand as any method of `B` can not see any `private` method of its super class.